# Having aliasing edges when using Imagick in php to convert PDF to PNG

Tags: php, imagick, antialiasing

When I am converting PDF to PNG, I got a aliasing edges around the image (which is anti-aliasing in PDF).

PDF:
[no aliasing edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G28dL.png)

PNG from Imagick:
[aliasing edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S6EA.png)

This is my code:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution( 250, 250 );
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('white'));
$im->readImage('pdf.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE );
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
$im->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
$im->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);
$im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
$im->setimageformat('png');
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $im;
```

I have tried mergeImageLayers, increasing Resolution, set White Background under it, and increase quality. However, no changes happened. You can download my pdf sample with this link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljm64vtcdxgwqnt/pdf.pdf?dl=0

Comment: U can now download the pdf in my dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljm64vtcdxgwqnt/pdf.pdf?dl=0

If you look closely, the color icon in PDF version looks great but PNG version has aliased edge. I can't make the same output when I convert PDF on the free online convertor.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution of a PDF is arbritrary we could say each inch represents a kilometre and if our Units of Resolution are millimetres we could plot every 1 m square on a map, however for a sheet of printing paper that would be too crude so we use a finer convenient resolution of say 72000 mils per inch and declare that as 72 printers points per inch.

When we place vectors that have no thickness it makes for a well defined edge with no noticeable problems, until we need to convert them to pixels for imagery.

So ideally an image at 1000 dpi would be nice since any aliasing of vector edges would be hardly noticeable when zoomed out by 1000 to show that inch at 100 percent.

However the storage requirement would be  horrific for coloured graphics as each square inch could, for highest fidelity, require up to 64 Mb of data storage. Thus we look for ways to minimise that by dropping bits per colour or reducing pixels per inch. In some cases one can make much more of an effect that the other but if both are optimised its even better.
[image]

**Here zoom into the original we can see how the high resolution source image is anti-aliased compared to the vector edge of the font.**

For graphics a PNG at 256 colours rather than 16.7 million may not look very  different if we are not worried about photographs. Likewise for thermal printing 2 colours would do. However that introduces more noticeable aliasing when sloping vectors are translated as the colour steps are more noticeable at lower resolutions such as 72 dpi.

So for the pdf in hand what might be an optimal compromise for this image @ a reasonable 600 dpi. However as a PDF that would become at least 128 KB bytes

[image]

If we drop resolution to 300 the letters will be less smooth when zoomed in and the rounded edges would also be degraded but we can hold the colours down to 256 to compensate and get a relative storage requirement of 25%
[image]

There is no way to avoid aliasing of vectors into pixels but we can use coloured anti-aliasing to our advantage if we work in conjunction with pixel resolution.

Stored in a PDF with the extra info that **300 dpi image is 16,330 bytes** and as a full page PDF it becomes 41,961 bytes thus much smaller storage than the source pdf.pdf which was 72,626 bytes and appearance is not much worse

The php example is 1128 colours @ 150 dpi thus should be worse
[image]

And as pdf to image 125 colours @ 200 dpi is scale-wise 33% better than 150
[image]

It is finding the sweet balance in each case between colours and resolution that reflects apparent visual quality, there is no imagemagic it is test and adjust that gets closer to a human acceptable compromise, on a case by case basis. The PDF is not the factor other than it holds vector objects like text or SVG it is the conversion of mixed scale images enblock that distorts their output.

Comment: Thanks for replying KJ. I understand pixel picture can't do nice thing as vector form. However, the problem is: my pic generate from my code doesn't have a nice render edge.

Here is the pic generated from my PHP code (png 157kb, horrible aliasing icon)
https://yudans.net/test.php

Here is the pic generated from online PDF to PNG convertor (png 160kb, icon much better)
https://yudans.net/pic_preview.php?id=1466&page=1

Both resolution and size is similar so I think it is issue about coding, with merging layer code needed? Or because the pdf icon is using semi-transparent edge? etc

Comment: So in imagick, how can I define the colors to around 125, and 200 dpi, to get the result of "pdf image" version instead of "php example" version ?

Comment: I want to have more idea on PHP code to solving this question.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: the result image has no changes at all..

Comment: no, it is still the same. Btw, i have set the bg color of php to pink, to let you understand the border of the images. Please visit again in https://yudans.net/test.php

Comment: Still nothing to change @@

Comment: After setResolution instead of only setImageResolution, it changes something. However, as u said, this will only increase the resolution of the images, but not the render technique about the color. It seems looks better just because we zoom out the large image. My image from PNG convertor is what I want, even the image resolution is small, the color is still good.